# Layout que ocupe toda la pantalla en cualquier terminal

Tags: android, android-studio

Me encuentro con que al probar mi app en el movil, o al cambiar el emulador con otras dimensiones mayores. sobra pantalla, es decir que se queda pantalla en blanca. Y si si emulo o pruebo en terminales mas pequeños, pues se corta Que pautas tengo que seguir para que independientemente del terminal que abra la app, ocupe toda la pantalla ? Uso las unidades de medida "dp"

Antes de actualizar Android Studio, nada mas crear un proyecto los layouts tenían un RelativeLayout y dentro jugando con layout_below independientemente de con que terminal emulase siempre quedaba bien.

Ahora después de actualizar no me aparece esa opción de layout_below

**EDIT:** Estoy viendo que hay crear unas carpetas en res con las distintas combinaciones de tamaño de pantalla, anchuras, alturas, y densidad de las pantallas.

Alguien sabe o sabe donde consultar, todas las carpetas con las combinaciones posibles de los tamaños y densidades ?? para solo tener que ir haciendo los layouts de todas las combinaciones

**EDIT:** Encontré esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiere decir que tengo que hacermes todas las convinaciones ??

EJemplos:

layout-large-ldpi
layout-large-mdpi
layout-large-hdpi
layout-large-xdpi
layout-large-xxdpi
layout-large-xxxdpi

layput-xlarge-ldpi
layput-xlarge-mdpi
layput-xlarge-hdpi
layput-xlarge-xdpi
layput-xlarge-xxdpi
layput-xlarge-xxxdpi

Tendría que hacer todos esos layout e ir haciendo el diseño de cada uno de ellos para que se vea en cualquier dispositivo correctamente ?

Comment: No hace falta que crees un layout por cada tipo de pantalla, como mucho haría 2, uno para landscape y otro para portrait. Y en cuanto a lo de que se vea blanco, prueba a utilzar el ConstraitLayout. Aquí te dejo el enlace de Android Developers interesante sobre el tema y como hacer una buena UI [
Build a Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/)

Comment: @kronosXXI Justo hoy miré lo del ConstraitLayout, pero para lo que quiero hacer no me funciona. Lo que quiero es que 4 botones ocupen toda la pantalla, le pongo el ancho match_parent y siempre ocupa el ancho, pero el alto le tengo que poner una cantidad fija o wrap content, y si lo simulo en una pantalla más grande sobra pantalla por abajo, y si lo emulo en una pantalla mas grande, se queda corta la pantalla de alto. Lo ideal sería que todo ampliara o disminuyera

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar las guidelines con porcentaje (al 25%, 50% y 75%) para anclar ahí los ConstraintVerticales y luego darle valor a la altura de los botones con un wrap_contraint.

Sería algo así:

```
<Button
        android:text="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"/>
<Button
        android:text="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"/>
<Button
        android:text="3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/button3" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"/>
<Button
        android:text="4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"/>
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25"/>
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:id="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75"/>
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso me bastó con añadir un match_parent al width y al height del ConstraintLayout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/logo"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

Si lo que deseas es que varias Views (en tu caso Buttons) ocupen todo el alto del Layout contenedor de las vistas (Buttons) deberías de establecer el parámetro layout_weight de cada View (Button en este caso) con el mismo valor para todos los Buttons (ejemplo: android: Layout_weight = 1) y no olvidar establecer en 0dp el parámetro del alto del Button que será el que corresponderá con el weight que has establecido, de modo que todos ocupen lo mismo en todo el Layout contenedor (ejemplo: android:layout_height = 0dp), dejando el parámetro layout_width en match_parent si deseas que te ocupe todo el ancho del Layout.

Espero haberme explicado lo suficiente.

En este enlace se explica, pero usando LinearLayout:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear

Un saludo, suerte.